# Передача данных из формы в html документ

Tags: php, html

У меня такой вопрос: как сделать с помощью php так, чтобы после того, как пользователь заполнил поля формы и нажал кнопку отправить, данные из этой формы сохранялись в файл с определённым оформлением?

Comment: Максим, тебе надо, чтобы данные не пропадали после заполнения формы, чтобы они выводились на страницу или записывались в текстовой файл?

Comment: Мне надо чтобы данные не пропадали и сохранялись в html документ с готовым шаблоном

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте шаблон сохраняемого файла. В соответствующие места подставляйте переменные из формы (после проверки, естественно). И записывайте в файл  [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-put-contents.php) .

form.php  форма вызывает сама себя:

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['city']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
    $template = '
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Имя:</td>
        <td>'.$_POST['name'].'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City:</td>
        <td>'.$_POST['city'].'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td>'.$_POST['email'].'</td>
    </tr>
</table>
';
file_put_contents('file.html',$template);
};
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>form</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="form.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" />Name<br />
<input type="text" name="city" />City<br />
<input type="text" name="email" />Email<br />
<input type="submit" />
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

В этой же директории создастся файл с данными. Также проверьте права на запись у данной директории.

Comment: А как создать шаблон формы? У меня есть html форма с полями и обработчик формы.

Comment: Хорошо, он создал файл, но файл пустой и не имеет никакой информации. Что делать?

Comment: Как это пустой?

Answer (score 0):

Ну так проверьте, приходят ли $_POST['name'] и так далее. Ведь первым делом проверка идет, и уже после успешного прохождения проверки, присваивается значение переменной $template. А у Вас, видимо, посты пустыми приходят.